# Why does `nsenter` need to call `fork` before `exec` to ensure that any children will also be in the newly entered PID namespace?

Tags: linux, debian, process, namespace, container

I assume that `nsenter`, which runs as a sub-process of `bash`, utilizes the `setns` system call to join an existing namespace and then executes the specified program using `exec`.

But, if `nsenter` has already called `setns` before `exec`'ing, why is the `fork` system call needed to ensure that child processes will also be in the entered namespace?

[`man namespaces`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html):

```
setns(2)
      The setns(2) system call allows the calling process to join an
      existing namespace.  The namespace to join is specified via a
      file descriptor that refers to one of the /proc/[pid]/ns files
      described below.
```

[`man nsenter`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html):

```
...
-F, --no-fork
      Do not fork before exec'ing the specified program.  By
      default, when entering a PID namespace, nsenter calls fork
      before calling exec so that any children will also be in the
      newly entered PID namespace.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation is given in the “PID namespace” section of [`man nsenter`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html):

> Children will have a set of PID to process mappings separate
>                 from the `nsenter` process.
>                 `nsenter` will fork by default if changing the PID namespace,
>                 so that the new program and its children share the same PID
>                 namespace and are visible to each other.  If `--no-fork` is
>                 used, the new program will be exec'ed without forking.

(The manual is somewhat messed up there; I’ve cleaned the quoted section up above, and [the next release of `util-linux` will include a fix](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=32ff1494e3bbf995199ad6d4bde911a3bab7ccf6).)

Entering a PID namespace doesn’t move the current process to that namespace, it only causes new children to be created in that namespace. As a result, the current process (the one calling `setns`) isn’t visible to its children in the new namespace. To avoid this, `nsenter` enters the new namespace, then forks, which results in a new `nsenter` in the new namespace, and then calls `exec`; as a result, the exec’ed program is in the new namespace.

See also the description of PID namespaces in [`man setns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html):

> If *fd* refers to a PID namespace, the semantics are somewhat
>                 different from other namespace types: reassociating the
>                 calling thread with a PID namespace changes only the PID
>                 namespace that subsequently created child processes of the
>                 caller will be placed in; it does not change the PID namespace
>                 of the caller itself.

You’ll see this in action in the `/proc` namespace entries: `/proc/.../ns` has two PID entries, `pid` (the process’ namespace) and `pid_for_children` (the namespace used for new children).

(`exec` on its own doesn’t create new processes.)

Comment: Thank you. `exec` doesn't create a new process, but only replaces the current process image, right? So, its PID will stay the same? I thought that entering a namespace caused the process to **move** to that namespace. So, the only way for a process to really **move** to another namespace is to first call `setns(2)` followed by `fork(2)`?

Comment: Is this behaving of "entering" a namespace, i.e. the process isn't really in the entered namespace, only its children, shared between all namespace types? And does it affect children that were created before calling `setns(2)` in the general case?

Comment: See the section of `man setns` I’ve just added to my answer: `setns` behaves differently with PID namespaces compared to other namespace types, it doesn’t move the calling process to the new namespace. Children created before the `setns` call aren’t affected (for all namespaces, including PID namespaces).